# How to invert a brush texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I want to invert the colors of a texture brush. How can I do that in Blender without using an external program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Texture node, which is supported by the texture paint system, too. Actually, it can be much more powerful than just inverting colors.

1. Open a Node Editor. In the header, switch the Node Type to **Texture**, and the Data Type to **Brush**;
2. Add an existing **Texture** or **Image** node, link it to an **Invert** node before **Output**. As shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this answer, very helpfull. Now i tried this: paint a stone soil as uv-texture and save this texture. Then i wanted to use this saved texture as inverted Mask Texture. To do this, i tried to create a new paint brush, open node editor for texture brushes, create texture input and select this texture. Unfortunately i cannot find this texture in the selection list of texture input. I wanted to use this whole texture to invert it, then to use as as mask for texture painting. Otherwise the mask texture will not meet the painted whole texture. How can i realize this?

Comment: @grenzfrequence You may want to ask a separate question for that (with screenshots etc.)